# Creating my html element in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

ok, so.. This code works as it is, but I need to add even more classes to the list item. what is the most efficient way to do so? Ideally the function will allow me to make each list item editable... thats not important at the moment, but that is the future plan.

```
var html = ""; // html to put into list
for (var i = 0; i < window.listings.length; i++) { // window.listings is a list
    var card = window.listings[i]; // get a listing
    //          console.log(card.card_name);
    //window.listings[i].seq = i;
    html += "<li class='list-item ui-state-default' id=" + i + ">" + card.card_name + ' - ' + card.price + "</li>"; // turn it into a html string with id of its position in window.listings (i)
}
//console.log($('.hotList .list-column'));
$('.hotList .list-column').empty();
$('.hotList').append(html); // put new listings html into hot list
```

EDIT: Thanks for all the help all... I'm fairly new to this so my code is a mash of my gf, my boss and my own and i'm trying to keep up with it all in the process. I kinda got shoved into learning it before I even had a good grasp on basics.. so.. any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: check the answer below, if you initially checked it and it didn't work, check it once again, it's edited and corrected now

Answer (score 0):

built an addClass function if you want to do in core javascript:

```
function addClass(el, classList){
 el.className += ' '+classList;
}
```

EDIT: if you want to add that class before appending your string, why don't you just add it as you did for 'list-item'?

EDIT2: you can manage an array of classes

```
var classes = ['list-item', 'ui-state-default']
//then push what you want
classes.push('newclass');
html += "<li class="+classes+" id=" + i + ">" + card.card_name + ' - ' + card.price + "</li>";
```

Comment: OP doesn't have an `el`...just an html string right now

Comment: It is about to become fairly complicated, so I am just wondering the best way to structure the function to make the html string. if that makes sense? (I'm not actually sure how to word what I am looking for.. I apologize for that)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#idOfElement").addClass("yourClass");// add just 1
$("#idOfElement").addClass("yourClass myClass hisClass"); // add multiple
```

Comment: OP wants to ... *"add more classes to the list item"*

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery, you can use `addClass` function to add one or more classes to any selected element/s. See function below.

```
function addClassesToElements(jquery_selector, class_name){
    for(var i=0; i<jquery_selector.length; i++){
        $(jquery_selector[i]).addClass(class_name);
    }
}
```

So, after appending your `html` you may call this function using,

```
addClassesToElements($('.list-item'), "new-class-1 new-class-2");
```

Similarly, you can create a function to remove any existing class using `removeClass` instead of `addClass`.

Hope this helped.